# Cross Posting Recommendations

Tags: discussion, cross-site

From what I have been lead to believe, cross posting is a no-no on stack exchange.  However, I have seen at least one question now where there was a rather substantial consensus that the OP could benefit greatly from moving the question to Writers SE for additional opinions, but felt there was a very valid reason to keep the question here.

Do we have any direction on cross posting when the community seems to feel it is a good idea?

Edit: [This question on Myth](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/22445/3202) is the best example I was thinking of.  There are aspects of this that are **very** WorldBuilding.  However, Writers SE could provide a valuable alternative angle to the same topic.

Comment: By cross-posting, you mean posting the same question on two different sites?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Yes, that is what I mean

Comment: That specific question would be very, very off topic for Mythology, in case anyone gets any ideas.

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that the *exact same* question can't be valid for both sites.

If this somehow is the case, the question is probably in a grey area and not explicitly in the domain of both sites at the same time. But in any case, such a question would be a rather rare occurrence.

More likely there may be facets of the question which should be separated and then posted individually to each site with links between them. Perhaps the preamble information is the same or very similar, but the ultimate question would be different.

I'm guessing the most likely candidate questions would be those about the [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process). Those questions have the highest probability for a crossover with Writing, Role-Playing Games, or Super User.

However, [our help section](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) spells out some topics that could be belong under the tag [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process), but actually belong on those other sites and not ours:

> - General writing or storytelling (consider the Writers or Role-playing    Games Stack Exchange sites)
> - Software that doesn't directly relate to Worldbuilding (consider the    Super User or Software Recommendations Stack Exchange sites)

---

Edit, given your comments:

For the [specific example](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/22445/3202) you may be referring to. While the question "How do I create myths?" would be valid here it wouldn't be on the Writing SE. Where "How do I portray the myths I've created?" would be appropriate there and not here. So, reposting the same question without changing the focus isn't appropriate.

Comment: I added an edit to my original question, pointing at the question in mind (I should have dug it up when I first posted it, but I failed to).  That might capture what I'm looking at... questions that are well approached from two very different vantage points.

Comment: @CortAmmon The question is not a very good one. The question itself requires no background information on the specifics the OP provided unless the OP was asking for specific examples for their world. If they were asking for specific examples/ideas for their world, then it's clear idea generation, if they were asking for the general process then it's writing/storytelling and not world building. You'll note the highest rated answer ignores all the details that were given, but is valid for the question, but not this site.

Comment: I thought it was well written.  It is my opinion that the worldbuilding process fits under the purvue of WorldBuilding SE, not just helping individuals make their specific worlds.  The details were given in case they were useful (and the answers found they were not).  Personally, I find general rules for what myths should look like are an exceedingly crucial tool for worldbuilding... especially if asking for specific myths starts to border on Idea Generation on this forum

Comment: However, what WB is not so suited for is portraying those myths effectively, once the writing starts.  However, nearly an identical question, posted in Writers, would get a completely different set of answers from a very different view point.  I might recommend changing one word of the title to "How to *portray* a myth..."

Comment: @CortAmmon That's an interesting distinction and an important one. While the question "How do I create myths?" would be valid here it wouldn't be on the Writing SE. Where "How do I portray the myths I've created?" would be appropriate there and not here. Those are then different questions and not subject to cross-posting frowning.

Comment: That makes sense, though it does also point in the direction of a question which could blur those lines rapidly: "How do I create myths that both fit well into my culture and are easily portrayable in writing."

Comment: Yeah, I would say if a question could be asked on multiple sites, then it should be put on hold as unclear on any site, because the asker needs to be more specific about what they want.

Comment: @CortAmmon "How do I create myths that both fit well into my culture and are easily portrayable in writing?" is a question that has two clear faucets that should be, split, asked on both sites, and *linked for reference*.

Comment: @Samuel Maybe this is a discussion to defer until a later date, but I find there are things which defy division into clean facets, like the elephant being described by the blind men.  I find those topics intriguing, so I am naturally attracted towards pondering how to deal with them.

Comment: @CortAmmon If they defy division then they are likely unclear and don't belong on any site. The descriptions by the blind men can be used for different questions on each site (Ears SE, Noses SE, etc) and linked together, ultimately the asker combines the answers to make a coherent one they can use for their complex and multifaceted question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a problem for cross posting a question. But I agree you have to **shift the focus of the question**

Example of my own cross-posted question:

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12205/how-do-pilots-stay-disciplined-and-use-checklists-even-after-they-have-become-r

vs

https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/7967/how-do-astronauts-overcome-the-boredom-from-the-daily-routine